# Qualtrics programming question (using javascript to create a bipolar slider)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, qualtrics

I need to use bipolar sliders for a series of questions in Qualtrics. I saw some code on the Qualtrics community website to help get a label on the right hand side (otherwise, this is not possible for slider type questions). I saw one that recommended not using javascript (instead using <float: right> in html), but I can't get that to work regardless of if I turn mobile on or off. I have found a solution -- using javascript like this:

```
jQuery(".statement-container div").eq(0).append("<span style='float: left'>LEFT1</span>");
jQuery(".statement-container div").eq(0).append("<span style='float: right'>RIGHT1</span>");
jQuery(".statement-container div").eq(1).append("<span style='float: left'>LEFT2</span>");
jQuery(".statement-container div").eq(1).append("<span style='float: right'>RIGHT2</span>");
```

However, now I need to make sure the different sliders are randomized between participants. I can't figure out how to do this because the javascript is what is placing the labels in their respective locations.

Any help on how to randomize when these jquery statements would be really helpful.

Alternatively, if there are any suggestions for getting the simpler solution of using html to work, then the randomization problem will be fixed (meaning, I would be able to use question randomization built into qualtrics). As noted, I tried messing with mobile settings and that did not help, I also tried expanding the window size and that also did not help.